# var_dump and print_r cause white screen

Tags: get-posts

My template is very simple:

```
get_header();
$new_p = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => 6));
get_footer();
```

whenever I put `var_dump($new_p);` or `print_r($new_p);` below `$new_p = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => 6));`, it gives me the white screen.

Why on Earth would it do it??

This code is OK, though:

```
var_dump(wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type' => 'tdlrm_store_item', 'numberposts' => 8), OBJECT));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error log for the error message?

Comment: Oh my, I didn't. I have the display_errors on, and was just expecting to see the errors on page, completely forgot to check the error log. How dumb is that (
I've found what caused the problem, though. Someone had put a base64-encoded image into the post content, and the system ran out of memory trying to output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, memory was exhausted. Someone has copy-pasted an actual 2MB base64-encoded image into the post content, var_dump was trying to output it. Had to delete the image via PHPMyAdmin, because the WP editor won't open. Once it had been deleted, the problem was gone.